# $G \ne [G,G]$ from irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory

For a group $G$ of order 24, how can I prove using restrictions on possible irreducible reps, that $G \ne [G,G]$? A priori of knowing how many conjugacy classes there are, I can get to $24 = 1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 3^2$ or other sums, but how do I use that to show anything about the commutator subgroup?

I know if $G = [G,G]$ then it doesn't have abelian quotients, so I would think to try finding an abelian quotients, but I think that's just me thinking too much about this as a group and not in terms of representations, and I'm stuck how to approach it from this new perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The representations of $G$ of dimension $1$ factor through $[G,G]$. That is, given any $\rho : G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ where $V$ is one-dimensional, $[G,G] \le \ker \rho$, so we can think of $\rho$ as a representation of the abelianization $G/[G,G]$. Since an abelian group of order $m$ has $m$ irreducible representations, all $1$-dimensional (up to isomorphism), the number of representations of $G$ of dimension $1$ is $|G/[G,G]|$.

If $|G| = 24$ and $G = [G,G]$ then $24 = 1 + d_2^2 + \cdots + d_k$ where $d_2,\ldots, d_k \ge 2$ are the dimensions of the non-trivial representations of $G$. Now try the plan you proposed: by parity, exactly one of the $d_i$ is odd $\ldots$